# TraceSwitch and SourceSwitch - what's the difference?

Tags: .net, trace, traceswitch

So I'm probably missing the obvious here, but what actually is the difference between the functionality of the [`TraceSwitch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.traceswitch.aspx) and [`SourceSwitch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.sourceswitch.aspx) classes?

They both give identical summary descriptions:

> Provides a multilevel switch to control tracing and debug output without recompiling your code.

Are the Remarks sections are oddly similar to my eyes. Could someone please clarify the difference in their functionality and usage cases?

(For completeness, I'm using switches with my `TraceSource` object, rather than the old static `Trace` class, though I doubt it makes much difference.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is that `TraceSwitch` works with `Trace` messages whereas `SourceSwitch` works with `TraceSource` messages, which associate the messages with their source. So with a `SourceSwitch` you can configure your listeners based on on where the trace messages came from.

I agree the documentation doesn't directly point out the difference, but dig around in the related [`TraceSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) class documentation and you'll find this:

> The `TraceSource` class is identified by
>   the name of a source, typically the
>   name of the application. The trace
>   messages coming from a particular
>   component can be initiated by a
>   particular trace source, allowing all
>   messages coming from that component to
>   be easily identified.

There is also a sample showing you how to configure a `SourceSwitch` to turn off tracing from a trace source.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense. I must have glossed off that bit in all the information overload.

Answer (score 7):

The (older) TraceSwitch basically is a TraceLevel object to be used in combination with the static Trace class.

The (newer) TraceSource combines a TraceLevel concept with actual output methods.

As a consequence, in a large App you can use multiple TraceSwitches to configure Trace settings for different parts (GUI, DAL) of the program but all output will be send to the same TraceListener(s).

With a TraceSource you can have independent output channels. And a slightly better API.

Answer (score 0):

This explanation of the difference between TraceLevel and SourceLevel might help:

[System.Diagnostics hidden SourceLevels](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/System.Diagnostics_hidden_SourceLevels.aspx)